# Error in KNN, but I don't have missing values, why?

Tags: r

I'm getting an error when trying to run my code. I don't have missing data as I checked using is.na() in my dataframe.

```
CI <- read.csv("Census_income.csv")

CI <- CI %>%
  mutate(Sex_Indicator = ifelse(`Sex` == " Male", 1, 0))

set.seed(1)
groups = c(rep(1, 20000), rep(2, 12577)) 
random_groups = sample(groups, 32577)

in_train1 = (random_groups ==1)

quant_train_std = scale(CI[in_train1, c(1,5)])

quant_test_std=scale(CI[!in_train1, c(1,5)],
  center=attr(quant_train_std, "scaled:center"),
  scale=attr(quant_train_std,"scaled:scale"))

x_train = cbind(CI$Sex_Indicator[in_train1],
                quant_train_std)

x_test = cbind(CI$Sex_Indicator[!in_train1], 
               quant_test_std)

predictions = knn(train = x_train,
                  test = x_test,
                  cl = CI[in_train1, 15],
                  k = 25)
```

Error that I get when running the predictions variable:

```
Error in knn(train = x_train, test = x_test, cl = CI[in_train1, 15], k = 25) : no missing values are allowed
```

Link to csv file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N68aU812YqZZdksKocsPdOLOdtcU7YGIU_ydKm8uKow/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Probably not your problem,  but the code you provided has a typo. `ifelse('Sex' == " Male", 1, 0)`  .  Notice the extra blank space with Male.

Comment: Yeah the column has a space in it for some reason when I load the csv into R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got NA values in quant_train_std which(complete.cases(quant_train_std) == FALSE)
[1] 19991 19992 19993 19994 19995 19996 19997 19998 19999 20000

Comment: Thanks for that, I guess I should've checked for N/A values better.